# PHP in JavaScript for Conversion Tracking

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using WooCommerce for WordPress which uses a thankyou.php page once orders have been paid and so I want to use a conversion tag with Ruler Analytics to capture data from the order.

Here's what I'm currently trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RulerAnalyticsPayload = {
action: 'convert',
Order-Number: '<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>',
Customer: '<?php echo $order->billing_name(); ?>',
Value: '<?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?>',
Payment: '<?php echo $order->payment_method_title; ?>'
};
</script>
```

Any idea how I could change this to properly be output in the code so as the analytics software actually picks up the conversion and data?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

I make this plugin some time ago to solve this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-google-adwords-conversion-tracking/

If you see the plugin file I have this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var google_conversion_id = <?=$this->conversion_id?>;
  var google_conversion_language = "es";
  var google_conversion_format = "3";
  var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
  var google_conversion_label = "<?=$this->conversion_label?>";
  var google_conversion_value = <?=$order->get_total()?>;
  var google_remarketing_only = false;
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Victor. Any idea how I can translate mine into something similar? Had a go but unsure and still not showing up in my code when viewing the source.